# SourceTree GIT: Unable to pull, push, clone repo with error "Password authentication is not available for Git operations"

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

For the past 2 hours, I have been looking for ways to solve Git problem. First of all, I had actually cloned a repo to my local from a Git website months ago. Everything worked well (Pull, Push, Create PR, etc). Now, I am facing issue where I could not Pull/Fetch source code to my own local repo (I am using SourceTree as the client). I am receiving these errors on SourceTree:

```
remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations.
remote: See https://git.xyz.com.au/settings/tokens or https://git.xyz.com.au/settings/ssh
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.xyz.com.au/rea-systems/rea-systems-data.git/': 
The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I also tried to clone a new repo from another Git website but to no avail, and got the exact same error messages.

I suspected that it could be due to token, so I followed steps from https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/two-factor-authentication-2fa-with-github-in-sourcetree-402033499.html. After that I am stuck.

What could have gone wrong?? How do I fix this issue?

Note: I did not change any settings on SourceTree (also, I notice that SourceTree keeps prompting for username and password eventhough I have entered the credentials).

Comment: Probably too late for OP, but anyway: Please read the errror message. My translation goes like this. Someone changed the server configuration and you need a certificate instead of a password to operate git on remote 'https://git.xyz.com.au/rea-systems/rea-systems-data.git/'

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an https url credential issue.
That could be the result of a [git credential (wrong) credentials caching](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).

First, for testing, try and switch your url to an ssh one, to see if the issue persists: that would sidestep the https crerdential as well as the possible 2fa scheme.